# How to check if my form is reaching the post limit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a large HTML form which I think is reaching the php post limit because the last parts of the data are getting missed off although it there anyway to test/be sure that this is the cause?

I understand this can easily be fixed by increasing the php.ini values, but is there anyway in PHP to check this is the cause in PHP?

e.g: it writes a log showing the amount of posted data sent by the form and checks this against the value in the php.ini

Comment: Can you provide example?

Comment: Please provide the HTML and the PHP code that you are using to check the POST data.

Comment: I can, but dont think this would help because its just a large form nothing special and works 99% of the time so there is no coding mistake. The issue is only shown now when there is more data added to the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your php installation is using suhosin, ensure that the following values are appropriate:

```
suhosin.request.max_vars
suhosin.post.max_vars
```

They will limit the number of accepted POST variables php receives (http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1513000).

To find the length of the POST data, you may be able to use $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Answer (score 2):

There are three factors

- Post_max_size in PHP (use phpinfo() for get limit)
- LimitRequestBody in Apache
- MaxClientRequestBuffer on IIS

Comment: I understand the fiz and why etc, but is there anyway in PHP to check this? IE it write a log of the amount of posted data and checks this against the value in the php.ini

Comment: While this info is accurate, I had always thought that hitting those limits triggers an error rather than causing data truncation.

Comment: If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty, so you can check these error via Ajax before sending form and return error message if limit is reached.